# Use twig in asset sentence

Tags: symfony, twig

It's possible to use a Twig result in `asset` sentence? See what I'm trying below:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    <li title="{{ entity.getName }}" data-id="{{ entity.getId }}" class="categories-first"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/dashboard/img/categories/{{ entity.getName|lower|replace("ó":"o") }}.gif') }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it's not loading the image since this `{{ entity.getName|lower|replace("ó":"o") }}` isn't evaluated, it's possible? How?

Also related to this same topic, it's possible to remove special characters from output? Let said á, é, í, ó, ú and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you use twig's concatenation.

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    <li title="{{ entity.getName }}" data-id="{{ entity.getId }}" class="categories-first"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/dashboard/img/categories/' ~ entity.getName|lower|replace({"ó":"o"}) ~ '.gif') }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work since I got this error: `Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",")`

Comment: I update the code. The problem with the punctuation was with the replace filter. Instead of ("ó":"o") it should be ({"ó":"o"}). I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the same error as before by trying to use this one `<img src="{{ asset('bundles/dashboard/img/categories/' ~ entity.getName|lower|replace({"á": "a","é": "e","í": "i","ó": "o","ú": "u","", "-","ñ": "n"}) ~ '.gif') }}">` what's wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a : change  "", "-" to "": "-" to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put your twig result inside asset. If you put this code below

```
bundles/dashboard/img/categories/{{ entity.getName|lower|replace("ó":"o") }}.gif
```

to your asset, then the result for image source is exactly as this code above.

Comment: I tried this way and for some reason it never renders `{{ entity.getName|lower|replace("ó":"o") }}` since in the generated HTML I see exactly the twig code

Comment: See this is the result `<img src="/bundles/dashboard/img/categories/{{ entity.getName|lower|replace(&quot;ó&quot;:&quot;o&quot;) }}.gif?0.1">`